# Why there is no __dict__ in the current module?

Tags: python, module

According to Python docs in the section "Modules" at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy, there is a:

> Special read-only attribute: __dict__ is the module’s namespace as a dictionary object.

But why it's not possible to access the attribute from inside the module itself (in contrast to __name__)?

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> __dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in <module>:
NameError: name '__dict__' is not defined
```

Comment: It's accessible via `sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__`, though I realize that doesn't explain *why* it's not available as a module-level global. I'm not sure any rationale has been given, though I suspect it was a deliberate omission to emphasize the fact that you shouldn't be using it directly (even more so than other dunder names).

Answer (score -2):

To access namespace you need to import `__main__`
Try this

`import __main__
__dict__`

Comment: This makes `__main__.__dict__` work, but not `__dict__` by itself. (You could use `from __main__ import __dict__`, but this still doesn't explain *why* `__dict__` is omitted from the global namespace, which is what the OP is actually asking.)

Comment: Yes. That's why I mentioned `from __main__ import __dict__`.

Comment: The problem described in the question is not limited to a module being executed as `__main__`. If a module `mod` is being imported (and not run directly), then an `import __main__` or `from __main__ import __dict__` would not work; `import mod` or `from mod import __dict__` would be needed. But still, this does not answer the question.

Comment: `__dict__` is nothing but a namespace function. It contains names for to use while writing programs in python. When the interpreter is loaded python loads namespace called  `__builtins__`. Thus for your question's answer, __dict__ does not exist when the enterpreter is loaded first. In its place `__builtins__` gets loaded. Hope that answers your question.